# Eval() PHP, usabilidade e contexto

Tags: php, eval

Eu estava lendo alguns códigos de extensões de e-commerce. Normalmente estes módulos são pagos, mas o que eu estava vendo tinha um 'trial' para experimentar. Instalei e fui analisar o código. Eu estava esperando algo em PHP mesmo, mas parece que os criadores tentaram **esconder o código** inteiro com a função `eval()` do PHP. Eu pesquisei [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php), mas os exemplos do [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) mostram um contexto de uso aparentemente diferente do que esta no trecho de código abaixo:

```
<?php eval("\x6f\x62\x5f\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x28\x29\x3b") ?>ŸÀ#0!0#T~8.…‚yAø-„_NuˆcEŒfU}l(N”p-S˜s-Tœx3Y |9_¤{#s!s#g¨Al¬„o_'&=\(.oŽÆ&R#r!r#½`U•‚B#r!r#$_NåÈ7Y#;wg#0!0#ãPs#r!r#ñ]~öf‹#s—1ž7$‘ªD2ž·{WØï&Bg©„#]öƒk×ÖzÅ{Ë4÷ø-4+7~QÊ0s\ò4Idm%géO÷~ôÞÝÜÝàÙUWÝóòóö¬§K#r!r#-Æ½¼½ÀÈj:S#r!r##n!n#Ï§ÂÍ¶¥ªöäõCEûÔ#r!r#=#n!n#ª€æ¤<?php eval("\x69\x66\x28\x21\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x5f\x65\x78\x69\x73\x74\x73\x28\x22\xb1\x22\x29\x29\x7b\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x20\xb1\x28\x24\xa1\xa1\x3d\x30\x29\x7b\x24\xa1\x3d\x73\x74\x72\x5f\x72\x65\x70\x6c\x61\x63\x65\x28\x61\x72\x72\x61\x79\x28\x27\x23\x73\x21\x73\x23\x27\x2c\x27\x23\x65\x21\x65\x23\x27\x2c\x27\x23\x30\x21\x30\x23\x27\x2c\x27\x23\x6e\x21\x6e\x23\x27\x2c\x27\x23\x72\x21\x72\x23\x27\x29\x2c\x61\x72\x72\x61\x79\x28\x27\x3c\x27\x2c\x27\x3e\x27\x2c\x22\x5c\x30\x22\x2c\x22\x5c\x6e\x22\x2c\x22\x5c\x72\x22\x29\x2c\x6f\x62\x5f\x67\x65\x74\x5f\x63\x6c\x65\x61\x6e\x28\x29\x29\x3b\x66\x6f\x72\x28\x24\xa1\xa2\x3d\x31\x2c\x24\xa1\xa2\xa3\x3d\x6f\x72\x64\x28\x24\xa1\x5b\x30\x5d\x29\x2c\x24\xa1\xa2\xa1\x3d\x30\x3b\x24\xa1\xa2\x3c\x73\x74\x72\x6c\x65\x6e\x28\x24\xa1\x29\x3b\x24\xa1\xa2\xa1\x3d\x6f\x72\x64\x28\x24\xa1\x5b\x24\xa1\xa2\x5d\x29\x2c\x24\xa1\xa2\x2b\x2b\x29\x24\xa1\x5b\x24\xa1\xa2\x5d\x3d\x63\x68\x72\x28\x6f\x72\x64\x28\x24\xa1\x5b\x24\xa1\xa2\x5d\x29\x2d\x24\xa1\xa2\xa3\x2d\x24\xa1\xa2\xa1\x2d\x24\xa1\xa2\x2d\x24\xa1\xa1\x29\x3b\x24\xa1\x5b\x30\x5d\x3d\x27\x20\x27\x3b\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6e\x20\x24\xa1\x3b\x7d\x7d") ?>Ý]@¦×Þò    Þ˜ƒ~›óæÅä5j Bº)¥    Ø°©)û:9:=Lå¤ ¹#e!e#LÉ'(-½K…½¾Ã«ƒuv½ØÙÞ¦2ÂPR%Ÿ¥ú85_·€U–—œJö|{|,»|'»¼Á_¼Œñ[YHBU¨Â¾Ö×ÜˆÿÇö\Œ…§É’G3ŒþÓ°†¦ #O0¹2ä vuvyxïZ[`ÂÁ¾Â[\a5Ì5ÎÏïVœ¢@ÜF®¯´‰¥{Ë+WÂ)åäåè‚^-‹òñòõŽ¡«®­¨«º³™†–Íëì$„°k‰ñ&PQ#n!n##0!0#WTKYZßíòòìéëìðêÞÖí#n!n#Akl%<?php eval(±()) ?>
```

Gostaria que alguem me explicasse um pouco mais detalhadamente o **uso desta função no caso apresentado acima**, gostaria de saber o **resultado** daquele código ali em PHP e também como fazer o mesmo procedimento para os meus códigos.

**edit1:** o trecho do código foi retirado deste módulo [aqui](http://all4coding.com/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments.html), arquivo `IndexController.php`.

Comment: O código foi cifrado e o `eval()` executa essa string como uma instrução válida.

Comment: pode me explicar ou compartilhar links de como isto funciona?

Comment: vc precisa pegar algo para traduzir hexadecimal para ascii, o primeiro `eval()` executa uma `ob_start()`, ainda estou ver o que é o outro.

Comment: Não seria o retorno desse site talvez? http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

Comment: Parece ser isto, mas esta parcialmente igual o código ali, ainda tem aquelas partes como `ŸÀ#0!0#T~8.…‚yAø` que gostaria de descobrir o que é. Obrigado por compartilhar o link, bem util.

Comment: Há algum motivo pra ter "usabilidade e contexto" no título da pergunta? Parece que não. Se não houver mesmo, seria melhor tirar do título pra não dar impressão errada na leitura da página principal do site. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[eval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php) — Executa uma string como código PHP.

No caso do código postado, estão usando o encondig ASCII na notação hexa-decimal, abaixo adicionei o código inicial e executei a função alert pra ver qual é o texto codificado.

```js
alert("\x6f\x62\x5f\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x28\x29\x3b")
```

O código é convertido da seguinte forma:

```
\x6f = o
\x62 = b
\x5f = _
\x73 = s
\x74 = t
\x61 = a
\x72 = r
\x74 = t
\x28 = (
\x29 = )
\x3b = ;
```

Você pode checar esses valores usando a [Tabela ASCII](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/apend/iso-8859-1.html).

Como estão usando o eval, ele irá executar a função após decodifica-la. Já o alert apenas exibe o resultado da expressão.

O seu código decodificado fica:

```
ob_start();

// segundo eval
if (!function_exists("±")) {
    function±($¡¡ = 0) {
        $¡ = str_replace(array('#s!s#', '#e!e#', '#0!0#', '#n!n#', '#r!r#'), array('<', '>', "\0", "\n", "\r"), ob_get_clean());
        for ($¡¢ = 1, $¡¢£ = ord($¡[0]), $¡¢¡ = 0; $¡¢ < strlen($¡); $¡¢¡ = ord($¡[$¡¢]), $¡¢++) $¡[$¡¢] = chr(ord($¡[$¡¢]) - $¡¢£ - $¡¢¡ - $¡¢ - $¡¡);
        $¡[0] = ' ';
        return $¡;
    }
}

±() // o último executa a função acima
```

Comment: E o outro `eval()` tem 3 no total.

Comment: Basta fazer a mesma coisa que fiz com o primeiro, pedir pra mostrar num alert ou no próprio console.log =D

Comment: Ótima resposta, se não for pedir muito, poderia me dizer o que são aqueles caracteres entre as funções `eval()`?

Comment: Cara eu já vi vários códigos dessa forma e acredito que seja alguma string pra ser decodificada, vou dar uma pesquisa depois qualquer novidade eu posto aqui.